# How to point to the previous version?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, application

The default gpg on my server is 1.4.20. But in order to do some experiments, I need to install gpg version 1.4.13.

I execute the following command:

```
   ./configure 
   make 
   make install
```

At this point gpg is installed in the default directory(`/usr/local/bin/gpg`).
When I used `gpg --version`, I found that the version pointed to is `1.4.13`. I want it to point to the original 1.4.20 version (under the `/usr/bin/gpg` folder). What should I do?

```
(base) :~$ type gpg
gpg is /usr/local/bin/gpg
(base) :~$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.13
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, RSA-E, RSA-S, ELG-E, DSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB
(base) :~$
(base) :~$
(base) :~$ /usr/bin/gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.20
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, RSA-E, RSA-S, ELG-E, DSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I modified it.

Comment: The usual setting is to have `/usr/local/bin` come before `/usr/bin` in `PATH`, so that admin-installed stuff in `/usr/local` takes precedence over system-packaged stuff in `/usr`. Ideally, you should have run `./configure --prefix=/some/path` and then added `/some/path/bin` to your `PATH`.

Comment: Yes it is. I now want to use ./configure --prefix=/some/path to install. But I just installed it by default. How do I delete and point to the original version?